# Two parallel flows of sequential processes

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have several processes, say A_step1, A_step2, B_step1, B_step2... They must run in the way that step1 has to finish before step2 starts to run. This is what I've done:

```
from subprocess import check_call
check_call(A_step1)
check_call(A_step2)
check_call(B_step1)
check_call(B_step2)
```

However, I want A and B processes to run in parallel. Is there anyway to achieve this in Python?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You probably can put related processes in a function and then run them asynchronously. For the asynchronous part, I would recommend the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html) module

Answer (score 0):

One common strategy is to use queues as a mechanism to allow a coordinator (typically your main process) to dole out work and as a way to allow workers to tell the coordinator when they have completed something.

Here is a simplified example. You can experiment with the random sleep times to convince yourself that none of the step-2 work will begin until both workers have finished their step-1 jobs.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager
from time import sleep
from random import randint

def main():

    # Some queues so that we can tell the workers to advance
    # to the next step, and so that the workers to tell
    # us when they have completed a step.
    workQA = Manager().Queue()
    workQB = Manager().Queue()
    progQ = Manager().Queue()

    # Start the worker processes.
    pA = Process(target = workerA, args = (workQA, progQ))
    pB = Process(target = workerB, args = (workQB, progQ))
    pA.start()
    pB.start()

    # Step through some work.
    for step in (1, 2):
        workQA.put(step)
        workQB.put(step)
        done = []
        while True:
            item_done = progQ.get()
            print item_done
            done.append(item_done)
            if len(done) == 2:
                break

    # Tell the workers to stop and wait for everything to wrap up.
    workQA.put('stop')
    workQB.put('stop')
    pA.join()
    pB.join()

def workerA(workQ, progQ):
    do_work('A', workQ, progQ)

def workerB(workQ, progQ):
    do_work('B', workQ, progQ)

def do_work(worker, workQ, progQ):
    # Of course, in your real code the two workers won't
    # be doing the same thing.
    while True:
        step = workQ.get()
        if step == 1:
            do_step(worker, step, progQ)
        elif step == 2:
            do_step(worker, step, progQ)
        else:
            return

def do_step(worker, step, progQ):
    n = randint(1, 5)
    msg = 'worker={} step={} sleep={}'.format(worker, step, n)
    sleep(n)
    progQ.put(msg)   

main()
```

Example output:

```
worker=B step=1 sleep=2
worker=A step=1 sleep=4
worker=A step=2 sleep=1
worker=B step=2 sleep=3
```